# Selected options in bootstrap selectpicker displays as undefined in angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

On clicking the search button, the selected item must get displayed in the console. But it displays "hey undefined".

This is my html code

```
<div ng-controller="filterController">
   <select name="model" id="model" multiple title="Any" data-live-search="true" style="display:none;" class="selectpicker" ng-model="select">
      <option value="1" ng-selected="true">Restaurant</option>
      <option value="2">Vegetarian</option>
      <option value="3">Bar</option>
      <option value="4">Night Life</option>
      <option value="5">Breakfast</option>
      <option value="6">Fast Food</option>
      <option value="7">Steak &amp; Grill</option>
   </select>
   <button  class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 25px;" ng-click="search()"></button> 
</div>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {      
    var select = $('select');
    if (select.length > 0 ){
        select.selectpicker();
    }
    var bootstrapSelect = $('.bootstrap-select');
    var dropDownMenu = $('.dropdown-menu');
    bootstrapSelect.on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        dropDownMenu.removeClass('animation-fade-out');
        dropDownMenu.addClass('animation-fade-in');
    });
    bootstrapSelect.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        dropDownMenu.removeClass('animation-fade-in');
        dropDownMenu.addClass('animation-fade-out');
    });
    bootstrapSelect.on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        var _this = $(this);
        $(_this).addClass('open');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(_this).removeClass('open');
        }, 100);            
    });
```

This is my controller function.

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('filterController', function($scope) {
$scope.search = function(){
    console.log('hey',$scope.select);
}
```

Could someone please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this, you use multiple so you get selected value in an array so if you want to console any selected value then you have to console like $scope.select[0].